# No ValidatorAction named number found for field JDeveloper 12c

Tags: java-8, jdeveloper, struts1

I am trying to migrate an application from Jdeveloper 11g to 12c. I am using Java 8. I am getting following error:

> org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm ValidatorForm validate No  >ValidatorAction named number found for field searchStnId 
>   org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorException: No ValidatorAction named  >number found for field searchStnId

It is working on 11g, hence all the file entries viz. Validation.xml and entry in Struts-config.xml is there, and I am using struts-1.2.9.jar and Commons-Validator-1.1.3.jar. Can somebody give some suggestion to solve this ?

Code in Files is as follow :-

```
       **/* _______________________________________________
        **Validation.xml**
        _______________________________________________*/**
              <form name="searchForm">
                <field property="searchValue" depends="required">
                  <arg key="prompt.searchStnValue"/>
                </field>
                <field property="searchStnId" depends="number">
                  <arg key="prompt.searchStnNumValue" />
                </field>
              </form>

       **/* _______________________________________________
        **Struts-config.xml**
        _______________________________________________*/**

          <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
            <set-property property="pathnames"
                         value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml, /WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
          </plug-in>

       **/* _______________________________________________
        SearchForm.java
        _______________________________________________*/**

            public class SearchForm extends ValidatorForm 
            {
                public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,HttpServletRequest request)
                {
                    StationLog.debug("Class: SearchForm :  Method : ActionForward validate() ");

                    String actionType = request.getParameter("actionType");
                    if("deleteStation".equals(actionType)) {
                        return new ActionErrors();
                    }
                    else   if("stnId".equals(request.getParameter("searchCriteria")))
                       {
                           searchStnId = request.getParameter("searchValue");
                           searchStnId = searchStnId.trim();
                            StationLog.error("Class: SearchForm : Method: validate() :: stnId: "+searchStnId);
                       }
                >   return super.validate(mapping, request); //THIS IS THE LINE WHICH THROWS EXCEPTION 
                }
            }


  **/*  _______________________________________________
    ApplicationResources.properties
    _______________________________________________*/**

    prompt.searchStnValue = Search Value
    prompt.searchStnNumValue = Entered Value
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Can you provide some code? This will help to get useful answers. What is `number` (Validator action?) ?

Comment: Hi @Ulrich , I have added code from the related files. Let me know if you need code from any other file. Thanks for replying !

Comment: Java 8 doesn't work with Struts1. This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.